# How to change DOM property of element created dinamically and have it variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a table dinamically from a json. That table does not exist from the beginning, is made with info gotten with an Ajax request.

The problem is, that I want to set a different  background-color depending on conditions for each cell. I have tried to asign it with a function, but doesn't work.

If I try to use something like
document.getElementById('id1').style.backgroundColor='#003F87';
does not work

What can I do?

```js
for (h=0;h<24;h++){
  i=h*2;
  val1 = eval("json."+(root+i));//concat strings and values to access h vars
  val2 = eval("json."+(root+(i+1)));

  if (val1 != null &&  val2 != null){
    table.append("<tr><td></td><td bgcolor = bcolor(); id="+i+">"+val1+"</td><td id="+(i+1)+">"+val2+"</td></tr>");
          }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would delegate the conditional background color to css. Just give the table an id or class, and style it with css.

[This guy](http://rpbouman.blogspot.be/2015/04/css-tricks-for-conditional-formatting.html) wrote a blog about it after stumbling upon SO question.